# Powershell monitor task scheduler

Tags: windows, powershell, scheduled-tasks

hi i found the following ps script that stores all the results of the enabled tasks

```
Get-ScheduledTask | where state -EQ 'ready' | Get-ScheduledTaskInfo | 
Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path C:\fso\scheduledTasksResults.csv
```

is it possible only store tasks with no path under Taskpath which are ones i created?

this allows to me ensure their running okay

Comment: I don't understand the question here.  Can you edit and re-phrase?

Comment: the above code shows all the task when they last ran | name | taskpath ect    i would like to only see task i created whixh seem to have no taskpath

Comment: You shouldn't store all task in the same path if you have a lot of them. They are like folders to get a manageable structure for your tasks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you can add a `Where-Object` Filter after the `Get-ScheduledTaskInfo` just like you use after `Get-Scheduledtask` full command would look like

```
Get-ScheduledTask | where state -EQ 'ready' | 
  Get-ScheduledTaskInfo | where !TaskPath | 
    Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path C:\fso\scheduledTasksResults.csv
```

the above will find any task with a blank `TaskPath` property.

However after looking at my own task scheduler it looks like you will still have a taskpath on tasks you created yourself, it will just be '', so in that case the correct command will be

```
Get-ScheduledTask | where state -EQ 'ready' | 
  Get-ScheduledTaskInfo | where TaskPath -eq '\' | 
    Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path C:\fso\scheduledTasksResults.csv
```